# Is whatsapp is available for iPhone 2G with iOS v3.1.3

Tags: itunes, ios

Is whatsapp available for iPhone 2G with iOS 3.1.3?

Comment: What happens when you try to download it from the App Store?

Comment: The app store should display the last compatible version for your OS when you browse the app.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, **no**.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/whatsapp-messenger/id310633997

> Compatibility: Requires iOS 4.3 or later. Compatible with iPhone.
>   This app is optimized for iPhone 5.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The last iOS firmware for the iPhone 2G is 3.1.3.
You have to use at least an iPhone 3GS to use WhatsApp.

Answer (score 0):

Sorta..

If you go onto a computer, and download it via iTunes, then go on the phone, and try downloading it again, it will tell you it isn't comparable, but you can download the latest version for iOS 3.1.3.

But... If WhatsApp changed the way they handle things, it may not work.